# how to validate a record in table before saving in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, actioncontroller

I am new to Ruby on Rails 
I have a scenario in which I have a form which has some fields. One of the field values I need to validate against a table which has the data .
I want to restrict the user from saving any data unless the field is validated with the table records.

Initially I added the code in controller to validate that but I have other fields which I need to validate as empty so it did not work .

Also I want the the validation error to be part of other errors.

I tried the below code in the model file

```
before_create :validate_company_id

def validate_company_id
    cp = Company.find_by_company_id(self.company)
    if @cp != nil
       return
     else
        self.status ||= "Invalid"    
     end
end
```

But its not validating , could you help me how I can validate it .

regards
Surjan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

instead of using before_create. You can tell the model to use a custom method for validation as follows

```
validate :validate_company_id

def validate_company_id
    cp = Company.find_by_company_id(self.company)
    if cp.nil?
      errors.add(:company, 'Invalid Company ID')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 19):

The guys answered correctly, but provided the other way for solution. You could ask yourself: "Why doesn't my code get executed?"

First of all, you have errors in your code - `@cp` is undefined. Also, I don't know what are you trying to achieve with `self.status ||= "Invalid"`.

You also don't have to use `self` when you're calling an attribute, but you do have to call it when you're assignig a new attribute value. So `self.company` is unnecessary, you can just use `company`.

I've also noticed you have the `company_id` attribute in your `companies` table. That's not neccessary, common convention is using just an id instead. If you don't want to alter your table you can set the `id` field on your model like so:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :company_id

  # ... the rest of your model code ...
end
```

After that you can use `Company.find` instead of `Company.find_by_company_id`.

Okay, let's say you have the following code after the fixes:

```
before_create :validate_company_id

def validate_company_id
    cp = Company.find(company)
    if cp != nil
       return
     else
        self.status ||= "Invalid"    
     end
end
```

First of all I would like to use ternary operator here

```
before_create :validate_company_id

def validate_company_id
    Company.find(company) ? return : self.status ||= "Invalid"
end
```

Isn't this cleaner? It does the exact same thing.

Now about that `self.status` of yours. If you would like to invalidate the object in `ActiveModel` you have to set some values in `errors` hash. You're in misconception if you think that a model with the status attribute of "Invalid" is invalid. It's still perfectly valid model in Rails.

So how do you invalidate?

You put some values into `errors` hash. You can also specify a message and the attribute you're validation error refers to.

So let's do it on your model

```
before_create :validate_company_id

def validate_company_id
    Company.find(company) ? return : errors.add(:company,"Invalid Company ID")
end
```

Now if you try to save your model with invalid company_id it will still pass and get saved to the DB. Why is that?

It's because of the `ActiveModel`s lifecycle. Your method gets called too late.

Here are all the callback methods you can use

#### Creating

```
before_validation
after_validation
before_save
around_save
before_create
around_create
after_create
after_save
```

#### Updating

```
before_validation
after_validation
before_save
around_save
before_update
around_update
after_update
after_save
```

#### Destroying

```
before_destroy
around_destroy
after_destroy
```

Notice how your method gets called long after the validation cycle. So you should not use `before_create`, but `after_validation` or `before_validation` callbacks instead.

And here we are with the working validation method of your model.

```
after_validation :validate_company_id

def validate_company_id
    Company.find(company) ? return : errors.add(:company,"Invalid Company ID")
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Inside you model, you can add custom validations as below:

validate :validate_company_id

def validate_company_id
  Your validations 
  Add error messages can be added as below
  errors.add(:company, "is invalid")
end
```